# Pinch zoom in Cocos2d v3.0.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I would like to implement Pinch Zoom on a Scene in cocos2d version 3.0.

I tried using "CCLayerPanZoom" in cocos2d extensions, but no luck, available at below link only supports 2.x versions.
https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions

Also tried using "CCPanZoomController" at below link no luck (supports only 2.x versions).
https://github.com/robertblackwood/CCPanZoomController/tree/master/CCPanZoomController

Answer (score 1):

You could use the normal way and do it with a UIPinchGestureRecognizer like explained [here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/event-handling/gestures-recognizers-tap-pinchzoom-rotate-swipe-pan-long-press.html).

To add it to a view, use the view you get returned from:

```
[CCDirector sharedDirector].view // returns the view that cocos2d renders in
```

This is what I do when I need gestures combined with cocos2d. The upside is that you can use that for anything in iOS, too.